# In Firebase with Xcode Swift, observeEventType function isn't getting called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the newest version of Firebase and Xcode and Swift 2.0 and i am trying to retrieve data from Firebase but for some reason the function `observeEventType` isn't ever getting called.

My Dataservice class:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

let URL_BASE = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

class DataSevice {

    static let ds = DataSevice()

    private var _REF_BASE = URL_BASE
    private var _REF_POSTS = URL_BASE.child("posts")
    private var _REF_USERS = URL_BASE.child("users")

    var REF_BASE: FIRDatabaseReference{
        return _REF_BASE
    }

    var REF_POSTS: FIRDatabaseReference{
        return _REF_POSTS
    }

    var REF_USERS: FIRDatabaseReference{
        return _REF_USERS
    }


    func createFirebaseUser(uid: String, user: Dictionary<String, String>){
        REF_USERS.childByAppendingPath(uid).setValue(user)
    }


}
```

My FeedVC class where I need to retrieve data:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class FeedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!    
    var posts = [Post]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        DataSevice.ds.REF_POSTS.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

            //this is not being called

        })   
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        print(post.postCaption)

        return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell") as! PostCell

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry the code Formatting is a little messed up

Comment: Is `DataSevice.ds.REF_POSTS` returning a value after printing ?

Comment: @triple.s yes, it prints "https://gourmetgram.firebaseio.com/posts" which is where the posts are stored so that is correct.

Comment: you are using older version of firebase , Go here :- https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

Comment: I am having a similar issue...Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: yes it was that i was indeed using an older version of firebase. When i converted the code to the new version it worked.